# How to fix the include statement error in Verilog testbench code?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, adder, testbench

I implemented the four-bit ripple carry adder using Verilog. However, I did not understand why the compiler generated this error

> Include file FBaddsub.v not found No top level modules, and no -s
> option.

Because I already had an include statement in my testbench code, I'm not able to understand why it's generating this.

All the files are saved in the same directory.

Verilog code: filename: FBaddsub.v

```
 module FBaddsub(A,B,s,S,Cout);
    input [3:0]A;
    input [3:0]B;
    input s;
    output [3:0]S;
    output Cout;
    wire [2:0]C;

    fa f1(A[0],s^B[0],s,S[0],C[0]);
    fa f2(A[1],s^B[1],s,S[1],C[1]);
    fa f3(A[2],s^B[2],s,S[2],C[2]);
    fa f4(A[3],s^B[3],s,S[3],Cout);

endmodule

module fa(a,b,cin,s,cout);
    input a,b,cin
    output s,cout;
    assign s = a^b^cin;
    assign cout =a&b|a&cin|b&cin;
endmodule
```

Testbench code: FBaddsub_tb.v

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
`include "FBaddsub.v"
module FBaddsub_tb();
    reg [3:0] A;
    reg [3:0] B;
    reg s;
    wire [3:0] S;
    wire Cout;
    FBaddsub test(A,B,s,S,Cout);
    initial 
    begin 
    $dumpfile("FBaddsub.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,FBaddsub_tb);
    A = 4'b1010; B = 4'b1011; s = 1'b0; #10;
    A = 4'b1010; B = 4'b1011; s = 1'b1; #10;
    A = 4'b0110; B = 4'b0100; s = 1'b0; #10;
    A = 4'b0110; B = 4'b0100; s = 1'b1; #10;
    $display("Test complete");
endmodule
```

Output generated by the compiler:

```
 \iverilog\bin\ArthimeticCircuits> iverilog -o FBaddsub_tb.vvp FBaddsub_tb.v
FBaddsub_tb.v:3: Include file FBaddsub.v not found
No top level modules, and no -s option.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce that error in two ways on my operating system (Linux).

The first way to get that error is to not have a file named `FBaddsub.v` in the same directory as `FBaddsub_tb.v`.  Maybe you have a file with that exact name, but it is in a different directory from the testbench file.  I know you said they are in the same directory, but you should check that again.

Or, maybe the file name does not match exactly because of a spelling mistake (like `FBadsub.v`).  If that is the case, just change the name of the file (or change the `include` line to match the file name).

Since the directory path has backslashes in it, I suspect you are on a Windows-type OS, and your OS is [case-insensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/165975/are-all-versions-of-windows-case-insensitive).  Maybe your file is really named `FBAddSub.v`, which is different from `FBaddsub.v`.  Verilog is a case-**sensitive** language.  That means that the file mentioned in the `include` line must match exactly, including the case.  If this is the problem, you might be better off if your filenames use all lower-case letters, like `fb_add_sub.v`

Another way to produce the error is if the file does not have "read" permissions.  In that case, you need to add read permissions to the file.

---

I am able to run the `iverilog` command without getting the error you reported, as long as the file names match exactly.

However, your code does have syntax errors, which you will discover once you get past your original error.